# How to get emailable-report.htm from a dynamic path

Tags: selenium, dynamic, path, robocopy

I am trying to add the emailable-report.html file to my out going Jenkin's email. However, I cannot figure out how to grab it as the folder name changes (time stamp) every time I execute my Selenium scripts.

My Selenium emailable-report.html file is saved into a path … “test-results/ 17_Dec_2018_08_05_AM/emailable-report.html”

By chance, does anyone know how I can handle the date/folder name variable (or find it) “17_Dec_2018_08_05_AM” from the Selenium execution into my Jenkin’s path?

Sperately, I tried in Post Steps, robocopy the file to a different folder : (no luck)

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Users\Public\BT-3ROX\Transform Supervision - UI"
robocopy ./test-results/**/emailable-report.html ./Archive/test-results/latest-emailable-report.html /E /MOVE /MT[:50] /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS /nc /ns /np
@echo on
```

With no luck to attach the file.

Any info on how to find/use the dynamic folder variable to use "17_Dec_2018_08_05_AM"(etc...)?